# check server runtime and internet trafic of PHP functions

Tags: php

I want to consult you.

I want to build a **'testing code'** of PHP functions, that will chek which function is better.

the 'testing code' need  to check:

- how much time (at milliseconds) its take to the **server** to run the
  function.
- how much **internet traffic** the function will use.

someone have any idea how could i check this things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to do a benchmark.

To know how much time a function needs, you can do it with this function :

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
$timeStart = microtime_float();
// your function
$timeEnd = microtime_float();
echo $timeEnd - $timeStart , ' seconds.';
```

The advantage of this function is that you will obtain a result in miliseconds, so it will be way more precise than a timestamp.

I would advise you to execute the function in a loop to obtain an average time, and to be more accurate.

For the network traffic, I think the simplest is to count the number of bytes you send, and the number of byte you receive.
In case of a curl for example, it should be pretty straigh forward.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For internet traffic I don't know a solution but for time of a function you could do the following:

```
$startDate = microtime(true);
YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE() {}
$endDate = microtime(true);

$neededTime = $endDate - $startDate;
```

Comment: And what exactly does the `timestamp()` function do?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Thanks I edited my answer. Amal: timestamp() does not exist... you are right... I mixed it up with a variable name in my script. Sorry!

Comment: @sHentschel: I think he meant time(), which returns the current timestamp(). Anyway, use microtime() instead for benchmarking.